# Formato de salida del mayor valor de una lista

Tags: python, lista

Tenemos tres listas (a, b y c). Tengo que restar las listas "b" y "c" a la "a".

Consigo hacerlo poniendo el resultado en valor absoluto como quiero.

Con las dos listas resultantes "b1" y "c1" creo otras dos variables ("b2" y "c2")  que suman los valores de cada una de ellas.

Creo una lista (resultado) con esas dos variables y calculo el máximo y mínimo.

Lo que no consigo es  que devuelva: **el valor mas alto es "b2"** en vez de **el valor mas alto es 0.29999999999999993** que es lo que he conseguido. Gracias

```
def sumalista(listaNumeros):
    laSuma = 0
    for i in listaNumeros:
        laSuma = laSuma + i
    return laSuma

b2=(sumalista(b1))/2 #sumo los valores de la lista b1 y se divide entre dos
c2=(sumalista(c1))/2
#resultado.sort(reverse=True)
resultado=[b2,c2] #creo nueva lista 
print (resultado)
print ("b2 es: %s" % b2)
print ("c2 es: %s" % c2)

def sumalista(listaNumeros):
    laSuma = 0
    for i in listaNumeros:
        laSuma = laSuma + i
    return laSuma

b2=(sumalista(b1))/2 #sumo los valores de la lista b1 y se divide entre dos
c2=(sumalista(c1))/2
resultado=[b2,c2] #creo nueva lista 
print (resultado)
print ("b2 es: %s" % b2)
print ("c2 es: %s" % c2)

#identifico cual es el mayor valor de la lista
maximo=max(resultado)
minimo=min(resultado)
print("El valor mas alto es: %s" % maximo)
print("El valor mas bajo es: %s" % minimo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque no es una forma muy buena de hacerlo (si el máximo y el mínimo son iguales, puede no salirte bien), puedes utilizar un diccionario en vez de una lista.

Por cierto, tu función `sumalista()` la puedes sustituir por `sum()` que aplicado a tu lista te suma todos sus elementos:

```
# sumo los valores de la lista b1 y se divide entre dos
b2 = sum(b1) / 2
c2 = sum(c1) / 2
resultado = {b2: 'b2', c2: 'c2'}  # creo nuevo diccionario
print(resultado)
print("b2 es: %s" % b2)
print("c2 es: %s" % c2)

# identifico cual es el mayor valor de la lista
maximo = max(resultado)
minimo = min(resultado)

print("El valor mas alto es: %s" % resultado[maximo])
print("El valor mas bajo es: %s" % resultado[minimo])
```

Comment: Gracias, más pythonesco, mil gracias